# VHDL Program Counter , multiple constant driver error

Tags: signals, components, vhdl, program-counter

I am currently attempting to design a Program Counter(PC) using previously made components.
The model of my design looks like this [picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWu8P.jpg).

The issue im running into is connected my MUX component to the PC register component. 
I am supposed to use the given signals but I am not sure how to connect them exactly. AS stands, upon compiling I am recieving

Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "PC_next[31]" at pc_update.vhd(52)

...

Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "PC_next[14]" at pc_update.vhd(52)

Error (10029): Constant driver at pc_update.vhd(63)

Error: Can't elaborate top-level user hierarchy

I know That is because I have two components trying to write to the same signal, which is wrong, I just dont know how I am supposed to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code I have been given, my implementation begins at the begin statement on line 41.

```
library ieee ;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

---------------------------------------------------

entity pc_update is
    port( clk: in std_logic; -- clock
        incH_ldL: in std_logic; -- increment PC = PC + 4 when high,
                                -- load PCInput when low
        PCInput: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- external input for PC
        InstrAddr: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ); -- instruction address
end entity pc_update;

----------------------------------------------------

architecture pc_update_arch of pc_update is

    component register32 is
        port( clr: in std_logic; -- async. clear
              clk: in std_logic; -- clock
               ld: in std_logic; -- load
                D: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- data input
                Q: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ); -- data output
    end component register32;

    component mux2to1_32 is
        port( sel: in std_logic; -- selection bit input
               X0: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- first input
               X1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- second input
                Y: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)); -- output
    end component mux2to1_32;


    signal PC_current: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- the current state of
                                                      -- PC reg
    signal PC_add_4: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- output from the adder 
    signal PC_next: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- output from the MUX

    begin

        PC: register32 Port Map(  --32 bit register
           clk => '1', 
            ld => '1',  
             D => PC_next, 
             Q => PC_Current 
           );

       MUX: mux2to1_32 Port Map(  -- 32 bit multiplexor
          sel => incH_ldL, 
           X0 => PCInput ,
           X1 => PC_add_4,
            Y =>  PC_next 
         );


    PC_add_4 <= (PC_current + 4);

    process (incH_ldL, clk, PC_next, PC_current)
        begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if  (incH_ldL = '0') then
                PC_next <= PCInput;
            else PC_next  <= PC_add_4;
            end if;
        end if; 
        InstrAddr <= PC_current;    
    end process;

end architecture pc_update_arch;
```

**EDIT** Since It seems needed. Here is the code for mux2to1_32 and register32
register32

```
library ieee ;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

---------------------------------------------------

entity register32 is port( 
clr: in std_logic; -- async. clear
clk: in std_logic; -- clock
 ld: in std_logic; -- load
  D: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- data input
  Q: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ); -- data output
end entity register32;

----------------------------------------------------

architecture register32_arch of register32 is

begin 
    process(clk, clr)
    begin
        if clr = '1' then
            q <= x"00000000";
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
           if ld = '1' then
                q <= d;
           end if;
        end if;
    end process;
END register32_arch;
```

mux2to1_32

```
library ieee ;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

---------------------------------------------------

entity mux2to1_32 is
port( sel: in std_logic; -- selection bit input
X0: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- first input
X1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0); -- second input
Y: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)); -- output

end entity mux2to1_32;

----------------------------------------------------

architecture mux2to1_32_arch of mux2to1_32 is
begin

    Y <= X1 when (SEL = '1') else X0;

end architecture mux2to1_32_arch;
```

Comment: There are two drivers for PC_next: the mux with it's output Y and your process ... You should decide if you want to use entities or a simple short process.

Comment: Your code is still not an Mimimum, Complete, Verifiable example, not showing the entity architecture pairs for register32 and mux2to1_32. The process actually performs the same function as mux2to1_32 and can be eliminated, (or alternatively the component instantiation labelled MUX can be eliminated). This was present in the question you deleted previously.  Instead of deleting questions fix them.

Comment: I was asked to make a new post by a user that was helping me, sicne the page was becoming very cluttered and messy to read. I had decided to omit the code for the mux and register32 since the other user didnt seem to need them, and I was trying to keep this one as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your process and the `MUX` instance do almost the same thing (assuming your `mux2to1_32` works as named). The process, however produces a registered output (because it only acts on the clock edge). You need to delete one or the other.

Note that for your process, `incH_ldL` and `PC_next` do not need to be in the sensitivity list, because you only look at them when `clk` has an event (which is already in the sensitivity list). `PC_current` can taken out as well if `Instr_addr <= PC_current` is moved out of the process to be a standalone concurrent statement - there is no reason for it to be bundled within the process.

Note also that you haven't assigned the `clr` port on `PC` and you assigned `clk` to `'1'`, which is almost certainly a mistake.

In fact, the components you use are pretty much entirely unnecessary. The whole design could be accomplished with 1 internal signal, a process similar to what you had, and a single concurrent statement:

```
architecture pc_update_arch of pc_update is
    signal PC : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
begin
    process (clk)
        begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if  (incH_ldL = '0') then
                PC <= PCInput;
            else
                PC <= PC + 4;
            end if;
        end if; 

    end process;
    InstrAddr <= PC;
end architecture pc_update_arch;
```

If you do wish to do an implementation with the components, you don't need to describe any logic at all - just the connective signals.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I never stopped to notice that the process was , infact, unnecessary. Guess my newness to the language is showing, I just assumed I needed to explicitly state what I wanted to occur. 
Yes I did want to use components, as this is part of a bigger project, sort of legos building upon each other.
I moved InstrAddr <= PC; out of the process and deleted the process statements. Compilation was a success, however the simulation [waveform](http://imgur.com/UosLu35) is not correct.

Comment: Im gonna assume this is due to the values I set for clr, clk, and ld. I did this earlier to fix errors of "used but not declared". 
 When I wrote register32, those values where controlled in simulation so I am not sure what to set them to.

Comment: So I kept clr => '0' and made clk => clk, and now my [simulation](http://imgur.com/ModN5aA) is correct. Now would this still work after mapping pins to hardware?